# How to solve AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I want ot extract feature from image,but i found the following error.How to fix this problem

[attribute error,when i run "exTrain3000 = getFeature([X_train[:30], 0])[3]"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAtnY.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without a [mcve] it will be hard to tell what is wrong. The Exception message implies you are trying to operate on an `int` instead of a `tensor`.. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.